# How to change source code in a running VSCode extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

How can I change source code in a running VSCode extension?

I've installed the VSCode extension `foam.foam-vscode` ([Link](https://foambubble.github.io/foam/)).
The extension is running in VScode.

For experimental reason, I wanted to change the string in `value` ([Link to source code](https://github.com/foambubble/foam/blob/b48268e20fd8ca0aced50a047e50eb459f1c4863/packages/foam-vscode/src/services/variable-resolver.ts#L212)).
I've changed the string under
`C:\Users\USERNAME\.vscode\extensions\foam.foam-vscode-0.19.1\out\services`.
Then I restartet VSCode to see the change.
But the change didn't apply. I just see the old string value `Title of my New Note`.

Any ideas?

```
async function resolveFoamTitle() {
  const title = await window.showInputBox({
    prompt: `Enter a title for the new note`,
    value: '### CHANGE THIS STRING ###',
    validateInput: value =>
      value.trim().length === 0 ? 'Please enter a title' : undefined,
  });
  if (title === undefined) {
    throw new UserCancelledOperation();
  }
  return title;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srwsnNhiqv8&ab_channel=TraversyMedia) at around the 10 mins mark to learn how to test the changes you made locally.

Comment: Strange, the changes should be picked up. Also, `Ctrl+Shift+P` > `Developer: Restart Extension Host` should be enough for VS Code to take the changes

Answer (score 2):

- Locate the extension folder in your system. For example, on Windows, it is usually under **`C:\Users\username\.vscode\extensions`**.
- Make a copy of the extension folder that you want to modify and give it a new name. For example, if the original extension folder is **`some-extension`**, you can rename the copy as **`some-extension-modified`**.
- Open the copied extension folder in VS Code.
- If the extension code is minified (not readable), you need to unminify it first. To do this, follow these steps:

  - Open the **`dist`** folder and find the files **`extension.js`** and **`main.bundle.js`**.
  - Copy the content of **`extension.js`** and paste it into a code beautifier tool, such as [[Beautifier.io]](https://beautifier.io/).
  - Copy the beautified code from the tool and replace the content of **`extension.js`** with it.
  - Repeat the same process for **`main.bundle.js`**.
  - (Optional) If you want to modify the CSS of the extension, you can also unminify the file **`main.min.css`** in the same way.
- Now you can edit the source code of the extension as you wish. You can use the VS Code debugger to test your changes by pressing F5 **you must be in any js file**.( if it doesn’t show up change the name in  **`package.json`** and id in the .vsixmanifest and try again)
- When you are happy with your modifications, copy the files **`extension.js`** and **`main.bundle.js`** (and **`main.min.css`** if you changed it) from the copied extension folder to the original extension folder, replacing the old files.
- Reload VS Code to see the effect of your changes.

**Note**: package.json can be modified to change the name etc. of extension

Answer (score 0):

If in VSCode you connect to remote host (with [Remote Development Extension Pack](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.vscode-remote-extensionpack)) then
you may need to change source code of extension on remote host (in case of Linux it is in `~\.vscode-server\extensions\` folder).

Then `F1` or `Ctrl+Shift+P` to open Command Pallette and try `Developer: Restart Extension Host` or `Developer: Reload Window`.